# Windows環境でPythonのシグナルを受け取れない

Tags: python, windows

WindowsOS + Python(3.7.5)環境でシグナルを受け取りたいのですが、受け取らずにプロセスが落ちてしまいます。
原因、対処方法についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

*receiver_test.py*

```
import time
import signal

def received(signum, stack):
    print("RECEIVED!")

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, received)
print("Start sleep...")
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

*killer_test.py*

```py
import os
import signal

pid = XXX  # receiver_test.pyのプロセスIDを指定
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

コマンドプロンプトを2つ立ち上げて、それぞれreceive_test.pyとkiller_test.pyを実行しました。

実行結果：
↓ killer_test.py実行後、RECEIVED!が表示されずにプロセスが終了する

```
> python receive_test.py
Start sleep...

>
```

Comment: 何かで対象プロセスをフォアグラウンドにしてから、[keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/), [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) あたりのモジュールを使って、実際にCtrl+Cのキー押下を通知してみては？ [Python “keyboard” module: Release keys to allow copy/Ctrl+C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57297394/9014308), [Python Window Activation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090464/9014308), [Pywinauto: unable to bring window to foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39794729/9014308)

Comment: ところでこのPyrhonはどのような方法でインストールしたものでしょうか？ 入手方法によっては挙動が異なる場合があります。

Comment: @sayuri AnacondaのGUIインストーラーでインストールしました。

Answer (score 2):

[os.kill](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/library/os.html#os.kill)には

> Windows: signal.CTRL_C_EVENT と signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT は、同じコンソールウィンドウを共有しているコンソールプロセス ( 例 : 子プロセス ) にだけ送ることができる特別なシグナルです。その他の値を sig に与えると、そのプロセスが無条件に TerminateProcess API によって kill され、終了コードが sig に設定されます。

と説明されているので、signal.CTRL_C_EVENT と signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT 以外は使えず、これらも同じコンソールを共有している必要があります。
なお、TerminateProcessはkill -9相当で、受け取ったプロセスは一切の処理が行えません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
以下を参照すると、WindowsでもSIGINT等が使用できるとあったので利用できるかなと思ったのですが、os.killからは利用できないということでしょうか。  
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/signal.html
また、試しにsignal.CTRL_C_EVENTを指定してreceive_test.pyを起動したところ、ValueError: invalid signal valueとなり、起動することができなかったのですが、何か追加でモジュールのインストールが必要でしょうか。

Comment: @yurika Windows で POSIX signal をエミュレートするのでしたら [alirdn/windows-kill: Send signal to process by PID in Windows, like POSIX kill](https://github.com/alirdn/windows-kill) があります。もっとも、これは外部コマンドなので python から扱う場合には subprocess などを利用する事になります。参考までにどうぞ。

Comment: os.killではできないと書かれているので（他の手段は知りませんが）少なくともos.killではできないと考えるのが妥当です。metropolis さん紹介のwindows-killは[SIGINTのことをCtrl+Cとして扱っている](https://github.com/alirdn/windows-kill/blob/aca0a17ca6a070007432504d137d58ad45e196b4/windows-kill/windows-kill.cpp#L51-L53)のに対し、PythonはSIGINTとCTRL_C_EVENTとを区別しているので、後者で受信する可能性があります。

Comment: @sayuri ご紹介いただいた windows-kill -SIGINTを試してみましたが、残念ながらシグナルを受信できませんでした。receiver側ではSIGINTとCTRL_C_EVENTの両方を試しました。SIGINTは補足できず、かつプロセスも生きたままとなりました。CTRL_C_EVENTの方は上記コメントにも記載しましたが、ValueErrorとなり、receiverを立ち上げることができませんでした。CTRL_C_EVENTはos.killでのみ指定することができ、receiver側では使用できないようです。

Answer (score 1):

コメントで紹介した記事を試してみました。Windows10 64bit, Python 3.7.6 です。
[keyboard 0.13.4](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)と[pywin32 227](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)の[Module win32gui](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui.html)を使っています。

対象ウインドウへフォーカスはこちらの回答を使用
[Python Window Activation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090464/9014308)

キー押下の通知はこちらの質問を使用
[Python “keyboard” module: Release keys to allow copy/Ctrl+C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57297394/9014308)

受信側のスクリプトは何も変更していません。

通知側のスクリプトは以下。CTRL+Cの通知

```
import win32gui
import re
import keyboard

class WindowMgr:
    """Encapsulates some calls to the winapi for window management"""

    def __init__ (self):
        """Constructor"""
        self._handle = None

    def find_window(self, class_name, window_name=None):
        """find a window by its class_name"""
        self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

    def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
        """Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to check all the opened windows"""
        if re.match(wildcard, str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) is not None:
            self._handle = hwnd

    def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
        """find a window whose title matches the wildcard regex"""
        self._handle = None
        win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

    def set_foreground(self):
        """put the window in the foreground"""
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)

w = WindowMgr()
w.find_window_wildcard(".*receiver_test.*") # 検索するウインドウタイトルはスクリプト名のもの
w.set_foreground()

keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+c')
```

CTRL+BREAKは上記の最後を以下に変更

```
keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+break')
```

結果は以下の様に、`ctrl+c`を通知すると`SIGINT`の処理が行われて`RECEIVED!`の表示で処理が続行され、`ctrl+break`を通知すると`^C`を表示してスクリプトが終了しています。

[image: WindowsSignal]

これが使えるか/使いやすいか、は分かりませんが、こんなことも出来るということで。

Comment: 私の環境でも受信できることを確認しました。プロセスでどうこうするのではなく、ウィンドウをアクティブにしてキーボード入力で対処するという発想はなかったです。1つの対処案として参考にさせていただきます。