# Python SocketHandler の受信待ち状態を解除したい。

Tags: python, python3, logging

#### 目的

Pythonでマルチプロセス処理を行い、各プロセスのログをログサーバー（といってもアプリケーションの内部プロセスの一部）にて記録します。
アプリケーションの内部プロセスの一部なので、アプリケーションを閉じる時にこのログサーバープロセスも正常に終了したいです。

#### 問題点

参考コードの中の、以下の箇所においてソケット受信待ちで応答できないため、ログサーバープロセスを正常に終了できません。

```
chunk = self.connection.recv(slen)
```

Queueのemptyメソッドのような受信バッファチェックでループを回せばよいと思うのですが、そのような仕組みはあるのでしょうか？

#### 参考

Python Document のLogging クックブック
[ネットワーク越しの logging イベントの送受信](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network)

#### 参考コード

Logging クックブックの受信端ソースコードをそのまま記載しています。

```
import pickle
import logging
import logging.handlers
import socketserver
import struct


class LogRecordStreamHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    """Handler for a streaming logging request.

    This basically logs the record using whatever logging policy is
    configured locally.
    """

    def handle(self):
        """
        Handle multiple requests - each expected to be a 4-byte length,
        followed by the LogRecord in pickle format. Logs the record
        according to whatever policy is configured locally.
        """
        while True:
            chunk = self.connection.recv(4)
            if len(chunk) < 4:
                break
            slen = struct.unpack('>L', chunk)[0]
            chunk = self.connection.recv(slen)
            while len(chunk) < slen:
                chunk = chunk + self.connection.recv(slen - len(chunk))
            obj = self.unPickle(chunk)
            record = logging.makeLogRecord(obj)
            self.handleLogRecord(record)

    def unPickle(self, data):
        return pickle.loads(data)

    def handleLogRecord(self, record):
        # if a name is specified, we use the named logger rather than the one
        # implied by the record.
        if self.server.logname is not None:
            name = self.server.logname
        else:
            name = record.name
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        # N.B. EVERY record gets logged. This is because Logger.handle
        # is normally called AFTER logger-level filtering. If you want
        # to do filtering, do it at the client end to save wasting
        # cycles and network bandwidth!
        logger.handle(record)

class LogRecordSocketReceiver(socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer):
    """
    Simple TCP socket-based logging receiver suitable for testing.
    """

    allow_reuse_address = True

    def __init__(self, host='localhost',
                 port=logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT,
                 handler=LogRecordStreamHandler):
        socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, (host, port), handler)
        self.abort = 0
        self.timeout = 1
        self.logname = None

    def serve_until_stopped(self):
        import select
        abort = 0
        while not abort:
            rd, wr, ex = select.select([self.socket.fileno()],
                                       [], [],
                                       self.timeout)
            if rd:
                self.handle_request()
            abort = self.abort

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(relativeCreated)5d %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    tcpserver = LogRecordSocketReceiver()
    print('About to start TCP server...')
    tcpserver.serve_until_stopped()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: connectionにタイムアウトを設定した後に、self.connection.recvを実行するようにすれば、受信できなくてもタイムアウト時間が経過することで次のコードに実行が移るのではないでしょうか？

Comment: この記事が何かヒント程度にはなるかも。[Shutdown for socketserver based Python 3 server hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48265583/9014308)

Comment: ちなみに、待っているのは`chunk = self.connection.recv(slen)`なのでしょうか？ 実は`rd, wr, ex = select.select([self.socket.fileno()],...`の部分で待っているのでは？

Comment: コミュニティユーザーによる再掲ですが、結果をどうしたのか気になります。ただあらためて考えるとメインプロセスが終了する時に何か特徴的な文字列を含むログメッセージを投げて、ログサーバープロセスはそれを受信したらそれを記録後に自分でプロセスを終了するようにすれば簡単で良いように思われます。

Answer (score 0):

コメントに書きましたが、ソケット受信待ちは`chunk = self.connection.recv(slen)`でしょうか？
実は`rd, wr, ex = select.select([self.socket.fileno()],...`の部分で待っているのでは？

そちらならば例えばシグナルハンドラを登録して、メインプロセスからシグナルを送ることで終了させる処理を行えるのでは？

参考コードに示された`class LogRecordSocketReceiver(socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer):`の、メッセージ処理ループ的になっている`def serve_until_stopped(self):`の`while not abort:`ループの継続条件および最後に`abort = self.abort`とあって、`self.abort`は`def __init__(...`時に`self.abort = 0`しているだけで`1`(0以外)にする処理は存在していません。

以下のように`def __init__(...`の最後にシグナルハンドラを登録する処理を追加し、シグナルハンドラの中で`self.abort`フラグ設定するようにして、メインプロセスからシグナルを送れば、ログサーバープロセスは正常に終了すると思われます。

```
def __init__(self, host='localhost',
             port=logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT,
             handler=LogRecordStreamHandler):
    socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, (host, port), handler)
    self.abort = 0
    self.timeout = 1
    self.logname = None
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.signal_handler) #### シグナルハンドラ登録

def signal_handler(self, signum, stack):              #### シグナルハンドラ
    self.abort = 1                                    #### abortフラグ設定

def serve_until_stopped(self):
    import select
    abort = 0
    while not abort:
        rd, wr, ex = select.select([self.socket.fileno()],
                                   [], [],
                                   self.timeout)
        if rd:
            self.handle_request()
        abort = self.abort
```

ただしWindows環境だと色々動作条件や制約があるようですが。
[signal.signal(signalnum, handler)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.8/library/signal.html#signal.signal)
こちらはOSに関わらない？

> スレッドが有効な場合、この関数はメインスレッドからしか実行できません。それ以外のスレッドからこの関数を実行しようとすると ValueError 例外が発生します。

こちらはWindows向け注意

> On Windows, signal() can only be called with SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGINT, SIGSEGV, SIGTERM, or SIGBREAK. A ValueError will be raised in any other case. Note that not all systems define the same set of signal names; an AttributeError will be raised if a signal name is not defined as SIG* module level constant.
>
> Windowsでは、signal()は、SIGABRT、SIGFPE、SIGILL、SIGINT、SIGSEGV、SIGTERM、またはSIGBREAKでのみ呼び出すことができます。 それ以外の場合、ValueErrorが発生します。 すべてのシステムが同じ信号名のセットを定義しているわけではないことに注意してください。 シグナル名がSIG *モジュールレベル定数として定義されていない場合、AttributeErrorが発生します。

こちらの記事も。
[Windows環境でPythonのシグナルを受け取れない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62459/26370)
[@sayuriさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/62460/26370)を参照

Comment: 毎々、回答ありがとうございます。助かります。試してみます。